# How to format Ecto timestamp

Tags: elixir, ecto

I would like to use in my template just the day and month of the timestamp `inserted_at` that Ecto automatically creates (`2017-04-10 16:22:43`) when using:

```
<%=i.inserted_at%>
```

As of today, what's the best way of doing this?

Comment: Like `<%= "#{i.inserted_at.month}-#{i.inserted_at.day}" %>`?

Comment: @Dogbert Exactly that. Thank you a lot Dogbert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ecto timestamp use are `NaiveDateTime`, you can show this when the representation in iex is like : `~N[]`.

You can use [NaiveDateTime](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/NaiveDateTime.html#content) provide by elixir like that:

```
date = "#{i.inserted_at.year}-#{i.inserted_at.month}-#{i.inserted_at.day}"
time = "#{i.inserted_at.hour}-#{i.inserted_at.minute}-#{i.inserted_at.second}"

date <> " " <> time
```

You can wrap this presentation logic into phoenix view for example.

By the way, when you have more complex date operation you can use `timex` deps.

Answer (score 2):

You can use https://github.com/bitwalker/timex, for example:

```
> {:ok, default_str} = Timex.format(datetime, "{ISO:Extended}")
{:ok, "2016-02-29T12:30:30.120+00:00"}
```

Comment: Yes. Timex is very powerfull but for now, I'll use the new NiveDateTime provided by the new version of Elixir. That you!